How to redirect files to multiple folders in ADF
I have a folder in Datalake Gen 2 which contains multiple files. Now I want to redirect all the files into multiple folders based on that file name. I tried with IF and Switch conditon in ADF but that doesn't work perfectly. Need assistance to redirect files to different folders in Datalake Gen 2
Needs a correct answer


Add a Get Metadata activity to retrieve the list of files in the source folder. Create a binary dataset pointing to the source folder. Add Childitems as argument in the field list of get metadata activity.



Then add a foreach activity to loop through each file in the list of get metadata activity. Give the expression @activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems in the items text box of for-each activity



Inside the ForEach activity, add a Copy activity to copy each file from source folder to different destination folders.

In source settings of copy activity, create a new dataset and give the container name and folder name where the list of source files exist. In the file name, add dynamic content and give the value as @item().name.




In sink settings of copy activity, create a dataset and give the container name, where you need to copy the source files. In folder and file name, give as @item().name.  If your file name has file extensions like .csv and if you want to remove that in the folder name, give the expression for folder name as
@split(item().name,'.')[0]


This way, you can copy all files in the single source folder to multiple destination folders.
